# jQuery add an item to an object

Tags: jquery

I declaired this object like so:

```
var array = {};
```

and I am trying to add an item to it like so

```
$.extend( {id: 'Cinematic', price: '2000'}, array );
```

but when I do a console log on my array its empty! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want those indexes added to array, array needs to be the target(first parameter) of the extend call. The properties are merged into the first parameter always. Also the extend method actually returns the merge result, so you could also use that. But this is what you want I think:

```
$.extend( array, {id: 'Cinematic', price: '2000'} );
```

Comment: even though this works, according to https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ as they say >> `$.extend( object1, object2 ); // Merges object2 into object1 `

Comment: "into object1" => object1 gets extended.
We want to extend array as far as I understand, so it has to come first doesn't it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be weird but somehow this work while yours doesn't!

```js
var arr = {};
var ar = $.extend( {id:'Cinematic', price: '2000'}, arr );
console.log(ar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```